# The method FileInputStream(File) is undefined for the type

Tags: java

What's wrong in this code? Still get error when declaring playMusicMethod. Sitting with this for about hour and still can't figure out. Tried to use this method in another class with only main method and It worked.

```
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;

    import java.awt.event.*;
    import javax.swing.*;

    import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
    import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
    import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
    import javax.sound.sampled.Line;
    import javax.sound.sampled.LineEvent;
    import javax.sound.sampled.LineListener;
    import javax.swing.JDialog;
    import javax.swing.JFileChooser;

    import sun.audio.*;
    import sun.audio.AudioPlayer;
    import sun.audio.AudioStream;

    public class MainClass extends JFrame {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

         JFrame frame = new JFrame();
         frame.setVisible(true);
         frame.setSize(200, 200);
        JButton click = new JButton("Click me");

    click.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            playMusic("Music\\somebody.wav");
         }
      });
    frame.add(click);
    }
    public static void playMusic(String filePath) {
        String filePath1 = filePath;
        InputStream audio;
        try {
        audio = FileInputStream(new File(filePath1));
        AudioStream music = new AudioStream(audio);
        AudioPlayer.player.start();

        } 
        catch(Exception e) {

        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: @StephenCorcoran seeing as playMusic is not declared inside the main method, what's your point?

Comment: @Stultuske my fault, when I did a copy and paste, it looked like it was

Comment: Can you put the error you received in your post?

Comment: Shouldn't there be a **new** on the assignment of the FileInputStream object to the audio variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are incorrectly instantiating your `FileInputStream`.

Replace this:

```
audio = FileInputStream(new File(filePath1));
```

by

```
audio = new FileInputStream(new File(filePath1));
```

Comment: the way your code was written, it was looking for a method named FileInputStream that took a File instance as parameter and returned an instance of InputStream inside your MainClass. That method doesn't exist, hence, the error message.

Comment: @BasicProgrammer if this solved your issue, can you mark the question as 'solved'?